# What is the best approach for migrating one Django app to another

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I am working on a Django project where I have to use South to migrate one application to another. I have the old internal message application which I have to replace by another completely different. I was wondering if I could pass by orm, but the old application doesn't exist anymore in the INSTALLED_APPS, so no sense. Does using a SQL procedure is the way to do that? I'd like to keep the application DB type independant at the time.

Comment: Do they share any of the same table sturcture? If not you are probably going to either write a python level script using the django ORM, or try some SQL migration depending on the DB you are using

Comment: In fact I have to take some values from the model of the old app which won't be present anymore in INSTALLED_APPS. I think that I will use sql, no choice. Thanks

Comment: If you find any libraries or things to help you, write an answer to the question yourself when you are finishsed explaining how you solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django applications are namespaced in the database so you ought to be able to temporarily have both applications installed. I would break it down to about three migrations:

1. A schemamigration to add the new application. If other applications need to have foreign key relations to the new application, add those and just make sure they are all nullable.
2. A datamigration to walk the model objects in the old application and create the equivalent ones in the new application.
3. A schemamigration to remove the old application.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, consistent and useful!

Answer (score 0):

1. schemamigration: python manage.py schemamigration myapp (with nullable foreign keys)
2. datamigration: Django custom sql is my friend -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/
   have made my custom data migration script keeping the project DB independent
3. remove the old application schema using 2.
4. (optional) a backwards rescue script